# Можно ли ограничить максимальный размер автосвойства?

Tags: c#

Есть авто-свойства:  **public UserModel User { get; set; }**, можно ли кратко ограничить максимальный размер, например 255 символов?

Comment: Можно, у `string` есть свойство `Length`, в сеттере поставьте проверку: `if(value.Length > 255) throw new ArgumentException();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данных не хватает (что за класс UserModel?), так что пример на свойстве Возраст (Age)

```
public int Age
{
        set
        {
            if (value < 1 || value > 120)
                Console.WriteLine("Возраст должен быть в диапазоне от 1 до 120");
            else
                age = value;
        }
        get { return age; }
}
```

Пример взят отсюда - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.4.php

Comment: Спасибо, выше ответ и твой очень помогли)